# Trying to get any tables th to display text in console log ,text depending on the th

Tags: javascript, function, html-table

I am working on a function that will eventually be able to sort all the tables inside a div based on the columns clicked.

I am starting small but I seem to go nowhere.
I want to be able to click on a th and have its text spilled out in the console log.

```
$("table").each(function(){
    $(this).find("th").onclick = function(){console.log($(this).text())};
});
```

Comment: It's **well worth** your time to read through [the jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com) beginning to end. It only takes an hour, two at the most, and it pays you back that time immediately by giving you the answers to things like this.

Answer (score 1):

When using jQuery, you don't use `onclick` and such. You use [`.on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/). You also don't need to use `each` here at all:

```
$("table th").on("click", function() {
    console.log($(this).text());
});
```

Alternately (and this is what I'd do), use event delegation:

```
$("table").on("click", "th", function() {
    console.log($(this).text());
});
```

That way, there's only one handler per table, but it's still fired as though there were a handler on every `th`.